# Easiest way to mount Google Cloud Storage in CentOS

Tags: centos, vpn, google-drive

We use CentOS for some hosting projects, but not very expertise with systems.

We pretend to use a main CentOS box to mount an "unlimited" Google Cloud Drive and then share it via NFS to the rest of computers on the VPN.

We already have `gsutil` installed on our Centos 6.5 and just want to know how to install and configure a local mount of Google Storage to share later in the private network.

Answer (score 4):

The utility you're looking for is gcsfuse.  Once you installed gcsfuse, mounting a bucket in the filesystem is as ease as calling :

`gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount`

Your storage is mounted on the filesystem and this allows you to access it as any other filesystem.  Reading and writing works very well.  Writing to the filesystem puts some extra pressure on memory because filesystem operations are queued in memory before being flushed to google cloud storage.

- Google documentation page : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gcs-fuse
- Github repo : https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse

Comment: Please explain a bit what this does.

Answer (score 1):

This application looks like what you're looking for. It's call [`gsutil`](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil_install).

> This pages discusses how to install gsutil, a tool that enables you to access Google Cloud Storage from the command-line.
>
> gsutil runs on Linux/Unix, Mac OS, and Windows. To use gsutil, you must have Python 2.6.x or 2.7.x installed on your computer. gsutil does not currently run on Python 3.x. Python is installed by default on most distributions of Linux and Mac OS X. Python is not installed by default on Windows; you must install Python before you can run gsutil on Windows.

Scrolling down roughly 1/2 way on the install page are instructions for using PyPi for installing `gsutil` under CentOS, RHEL, & Fedora.

#### Installation

1. Install required system packages.

   Several packages are required to successfully install gsutil from PyPi. You can install them with the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo yum install gcc openssl-devel python-devel python-setuptools
   ```
2. Install pip.

   We recommend using the pip installer. You can install it with the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo easy_install -U pip
   ```
3. Install gsutil from PyPi.

   To install gsutil from PyPi, use the following command:

   ```
   $ sudo pip install gsutil
   ```

That's it. You're ready to start using gsutil. To see a listing of gsutil commands, type gsutil at the command prompt.

*Updating gsutil*

The gsutil update command is not available when installing via PyPi. To update gsutil, use the pip installer:

```
$ sudo pip install -U gsutil
```

After installation, `gsutil config` will need to be run to configure.

Comment: gsutil can't be used to mount the disk. It does allow you to create, list, modify, etc files that are stored in Google Cloud Storage, using command likes like "gsutil ls". I don't think there is an official way to mount Google Cloud Storage.

Comment: Yes. Use gcsfuse for this, not gsutil